# Change Ellipse property on parent grid mouseover WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

I have a grid in which i have a ellipse, and i want that on mouse is over oon the gid the ellipse should be filled with red color . How can i do this thing ? if i place trigger in ellipse then its only on mouse overover with in ellipse. But i want that the color should be changed o mouse is over on the parent grid of ellipse .

Here is my code of User Control :

```
    <UserControl x:Class="DeviceIcon"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="31" d:DesignWidth="31">


<Grid Background="#00000000" Name="MainGrid">
    <Ellipse Name="BackCircle" Width="30" Height="30" Fill="Lavender" Stroke="Red" >

    </Ellipse>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add event handlers to the parent grid. The mouse events bubble up to the grid from the ellipse and other child elements.

**XAML**

```
<Grid Background="#00000000"
      Name="MainGrid"
      MouseEnter='MainGrid_MouseEnter'
      MouseLeave='MainGrid_MouseLeave'>

    <Ellipse Name="BackCircle"
         Width="30"
         Height="30"
         Fill="Lavender"
         Stroke="Red">

    </Ellipse>
    </Grid>
```

**Code**

```
   private Brush _oldFill;
   private void MainGrid_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
      _oldFill = BackCircle.Fill;
      BackCircle.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        }

    private void MainGrid_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
      BackCircle.Fill = _oldFill;
     }
```